# Google Cloud Function - ImportError: cannot import name 'pubsub' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am deploying a Google Cloud Function that will kick off other Google Cloud Functions using `google.cloud.pubsub_v1` and I'm getting this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'pubsub' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)`

The beginning of my requirements.txt file looks like this

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-pubsub
....
```

The beginning of my main.py script looks like this:

```
import base64
import json
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(<PROJECT_ID>, <PUBSUB_TOPIC>)
```

I am deploying this code from a Google Cloud Source Repository.  I have read through [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011713/importerror-cannot-import-name-pubsub-v1) about my error, but that question appears to be about this error arising in a Client application.  My error is being generated by the Google Cloud function itself during the deploy process.  I don't have `sudo` rights to the auto-created VM that Google is using to run my process, do I?  I should be able to resolve this issue from the `requirements.txt` file, but nothing I've tried seems to be working.

What's more frustrating is that when I put this same code in the "Inline editor" on the web-based Google Function editor, I don't get an error.  I only get this error when loading the code from the repository.

The current file structure in the repository looks something like this:

```
.
├── package
|   ├── main.py
|   ├── script1.py
|   └── script2.py
├── package2
├── ...
└── requirements.txt
```

I moved main.py inside of a package because of issues I was having in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432324/google-cloud-function-function-load-error-file-main-py-that-is-expected-to-de)

Any ideas on how to resolve this import error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `main.py` file and `requirements.txt` file should be in the same directory, and this should also be the same directory you're deploying your function from.

Also, the [`google-cloud`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/) package is deprecated and shouldn't be used with other `google-cloud-*` packages. You should remove it from your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: I get the same error with or without the `google-cloud` package in the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: I see you're using Cloud Source Repositories. Are you making sure to re-deploy the function after pushing a new commit to the repository? It won't auto-deploy.

Comment: yes, I push to my repository, then I run the `gcloud deploy ...` command in my terminal and that is when I get this error, during the deployment of the function.

Comment: Do you have a `lib` folder in your repository that might contain other dependencies?

Comment: Nope, no `lib` folder with other dependencies.

Comment: Any other ideas of things I should be looking into to resolve this issue?

Comment: When you're deploying, are you deploying from the same directory as your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: That did it!  The `requirements.txt` file needs to be in the same directory as `main.py`.  I moved mine into the `package` directory.  Will you update your answer to include this information and I'll mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

To install the `google-cloud` library, you need to perform

```
pip install google-cloud-storage
```

as can be seen in the official Google Cloud documentation, so don't install `google-cloud-pubsub`.

Nevertheless, you import the pubsub package as you did by

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
```

Again, a page dedicated for the pubsub_v1 library exists on the official Google Cloud documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-python) that shows the following example:

```
import time

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
# TODO subscription_name = "Your Pub/Sub subscription name"

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
# The `subscription_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
# in the form `projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_name}`
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
    project_id, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
    print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
    message.ack()

subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

# The subscriber is non-blocking. We must keep the main thread from
# exiting to allow it to process messages asynchronously in the background.
print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
```