# Accessing User-Defined Packages in Google Cloud Function (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...)

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, package, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying a Google Cloud function from a source repository.  I can get the Google Function to deploy fine as long as I don't make any reference in my `main.py` to any of my user-defined functions in the repository (i.e. scripts/functions in either `package` or `package2` below other than `main.py`).

```
.
├── package
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── main.py
|   ├── requirements.txt
|   ├── script1.py
|   └── script2.py
├── package2
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── script3.py
|   └── script4.py
└── ...
```

I have 2 recent Stack Overflow questions regarding this function deploy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432324/google-cloud-function-function-load-error-file-main-py-that-is-expected-to-de) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452269/google-cloud-function-importerror-cannot-import-name-pubsub-from-google-cl).  They have collectively guided me towards a solution where `main.py` and `requirements.txt` are within a package and I deploy the Google Cloud Function with that package as the source.  The problem now though is that I need to be able to access functions/scripts in other packages/scripts.  If I include a statement like `from package.script1 import foo` in `main.py` I get an error like the one below when I deploy the function:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in requirements.txt?
Detailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/wo
rker.py", line 211, in check_or_load_user_function
    _function_handler.load_user_function()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/wo
rker.py", line 140, in load_user_function
    spec.loader.exec_module(main)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from package.script1 import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

I am currently deploying this function with this google function deploy statement:

```
gcloud functions deploy NAME --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/repos/REPOSITORY_ID/moveable-aliases/BRANCH_NAME/paths/package/ --trigger-topic TOPIC
```

Moving `main.py` and `requirements.txt` back to the root directory doesn't work due to the issues in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432324/google-cloud-function-function-load-error-file-main-py-that-is-expected-to-de).

I need a way to import user-defined packages/functions during a `gcloud functions deploy ...` statement.  My `main.py` makes use of functions in `package.script1.py`, `package.script2.py`, `package2.script3.py`, and `package2.script4.py`.  How can this be accomplished?

### EDIT/UPDATED INFORMATION

I do have `__init__.py` files in each of the packages (`package` and `package2`), but they're currently blank/empty.

I have tried the following `gcloud deploy...` options:

1. `main.py` and `requirements.txt` in the root directory (instead of the configuration as shown above/originally) with this deploy command:

   ```
   gcloud functions deploy NAME --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/repos/REPOSITORY_ID/moveable-aliases/BRANCH --trigger-topic TOPIC
   ```

   This produces the following error:

   ```
   ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist
   ```
2. In an attempt to explicitly call out the root directory as source, I've also tried this with the same file configuration as in #1

   ```
   gcloud functions deploy NAME --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/repos/REPOSITORY_ID/moveable-aliases/BRANCH/paths/ --trigger-topic TOPIC
   ```

   It gives me the same error as #1:

   ```
   ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist
   ```
3. The using the original file structure in this question (with `main.py` and `requirements.txt` in `package`), I have tried the deploy statement provided above.  It resolves the `main.py` not found issue, but gives me the error as stated in the original question above

What else should I try?

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in each of your package directories?

Comment: Good to hear from you Dustin!  Yes I do, but they're still blank.  How should I be populating them to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your app like this:

```
.
├── main.py
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── script1.py
│   └── script2.py
├── package2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── script3.py
│   └── script4.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Then in `main.py`, you can do:

```
from package.script1 import foo
from package2.script2 import bar
# etc
```

Comment: That is exactly how I had my project structured in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432324/google-cloud-function-function-load-error-file-main-py-that-is-expected-to-de), but Google Cloud had issues finding main.py

Comment: Even if you deploy from the same directory as `main.py`? What error does it produce?

Comment: Are you able to deploy from your local filesystem rather than from a cloud source repository?

Comment: Do you mean using a "ZIP upload"?  There are 4 options on the GUI Google Cloud Functions "Create function" page: (1) Inline editor, (2) Zip upload, (3) Zip from Cloud Storage, & (4) Cloud Source repository

Comment: No, I mean directly with the `gcloud` command line tool, e.g.: `gcloud functions deploy NAME --runtime python37 --trigger-topic TOPIC`

Comment: I tried to deploy my functions with the structure and command from @DustinIngram but it produces this error: `ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File main.py is expected to contain a function named FOO`

Comment: @lmaonuts Does your `main.py` file contain a function named `FOO`?

Comment: @DustinIngram I have only imports in my `main.py`, no function declared. Funny enough today it worked just fine...